# Display custom overlay image when button is pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

**The Goal:**

I would like to add a method to my `UIButton` which randomly displays the following;

- An image in the middle of the overlay displaying a picture
- A `UIButton` at the top-right (red 'x') that closes the overlay
- Various UILabels with information

How would I go about creating an overlay, and how would I customize the layout of the overlay and assign values and images dynamically?

I know how to create a custom cell for a `UITableView`, but I need a bit of guidance on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IB or create by program a `UIImageView` to contain your image on top of the overlay.  Then just use the `button` to toggle the `image view` between hidden (property of `UIimageview`) and not. Alternatively you may position push the `image view` to top and put it down to the bottom of the view heap using the `button`.

Comment: Forgive me for not knowing this, but what does IB stand for? I like the idea of creating a UIImageView that sits on top of the view, but my concern for this is that I will be unable to format it because a UIImageView can only hold an image from what I understand. Is there a way that I can format a view that can be toggled in a similar way using a similar method depicted here? http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: IB stands for Interface builder - the Xcode editor for XIBs and storyboards. I probably didn't understand your original question-  The overlay can be created using any UIView type object  including UIImageView . The button maybe put on top of the overlay as well - just take note that if you have an overlay view as big as the base views and the background is transparent - the controls beneath it will be visible but not accessible.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. I apologize for being so late on selecting your answer as the best, but I have been on vacation. See you around, and I hope you had an incredible Christmas.